# Formula to find the split complementaries of a color?

Tags: colors

I'm looking for a way to find the split complementaries of an RGB color. I'm currently using Javascript, but that doesn't matter. I'm just looking for psuedocode or any code examples, really. I've Googled this question a few times but I can't seem to come up with any results. Anybody have the formula for me?

Also, I'd like to try to keep from converting to any other color formats during the process, as that can be a pain.

Comment: Even assuming you mean complement, not compliment, I still don’t know what you mean. I’ve done some work with colors in RGB space in Perl, though.  Could you explain more?

Comment: Whoops, yes, I mean complement. I'm trying to find the split complements of a particular RGB color via a mathematical formula. Trouble is, I can't figure out or find that formula anywhere, which is why I've come here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert to HSV then modify your hue angle by 180°±30° or so.

Conversions to HSV are common and easy to get. But you just need the angle bit, tweak it by the complement and then by the split and feed that sucker back into RGB.

```
rgb2hsv(r,g,b);
h += 180;
h0 = h + 30;
h1 = h - 30;
hsv2rgb(h0,s,v);
hsv2rgb(h1,s,v);
```

More or less. Pick up rgb2hsv and hsv2rgb from chroma.js or any any code base. Or grab copies of both and mash them together with just the stuff you want and make a single function thing to do it.